# Basic Jersey Rest WS in Tomcat giving "resource not available"

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I am trying to make a simple Rest WS with eclipse/Tomcat/Jersey but i am not able to make it work. It is getting frustrating because i don't see the error, but seems to be really subtle.

[image]

This is the content of my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>LearnWS</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is the Hello.java:

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

      // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
      }

      // This method is called if XML is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
      }

      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
      }
}
```

As you can see, is the typical hello world. But for me is not working.

I export the .war file, deploy at Tomcat web apps dir, open the manager (there it is "Learn"), but when i try `http://localhost:8080/Learn/rest/hello` i only see **The requested resource is not available** error. In the picture you don't see it, but the project is called Learn.

In catalina.out there is no error deploying.

I am using Java SE 6 (1.6.0_65-b14-462 for the build), and Tomcat 7.0.54 (JVM 1.8.0_05-b13). Maybe that is the issue, but don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using jersey 2.x.  Let your web.xml as follows:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Jersey 2.x refers to org.glassfish. Your URL would be "localhost:8080/your_App_name/rest/hello"

Thanks,
JK